# Statmodels output different from sklearn regression

Tags: python, scikit-learn, statsmodels

I am trying to get something magic from the boston dataset on sklearn. Wihtout making any change I did a regression with sklearn and another with statsmodels to easily get the p-value of my each of the variables used. However, my reults are completely different results.
Here it is:

```
boston_houses=load_boston()
boston=pd.DataFrame(data=boston_houses.data, columns=boston_houses.feature_names)
boston['MEDV']=boston_houses.target
boston.head()

X,y=boston.drop(columns='MEDV'),boston['MEDV']

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.33, random_state=42)

lin_model = LinearRegression()
lin_model.fit(X_train, y_train)
pred= lin_model.predict(X_test)

from sklearn.metrics import r2_score,mean_squared_error
rSq=r2_score(y_test,pred)
rmse=np.sqrt(mean_squared_error(y_test,pred))

print ('The R-squared for this model {}'.format(rSq))
print ('The Root mean square error for this model {}'.format(rmse))

###### scipy now ###
The R-squared for this model 0.7261570836552478
The Root mean square error for this model 4.55236459846306

X_new=sm.tools.tools.add_constant(X_train)
estimator= sm.OLS(y_train, X_new)
estimator.fit()

print(estimator.fit().summary())
```

I get 0.739 for the R-squared with statsmodel,Why??

Comment: All results statistics in statsmodels use the training sample. Your sklearn R2 is for the test sample. Check that the parameter estimates and predictions agree between the two packages.

Comment: exactly. I realized as well. Thanks @Josef

Answer (score 0):

If you are wondering why it is not the same as R-squared which you received from `sklearn.metrics.r2_score` than the reason is that you have used two different realisations of linear regression with different parameters which produced different predictions.

If you for example change your `test_size` to 0.25 in `train_test_split` you will have one more model with different result.

Comment: However, i have just changed everything and I have the quantity of data. on sklearn and statsmodels but still get difference results.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the test for the whole data on sklearn. The results finally matched.Silly from me. I should check how my training perform before to checking how my the sample test respond. That would help me to avoid the mistake acknowledging that there are 2 steps.